# How to leave some form elements blank after validating a Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have created a custom Zend_Form with validators.
After the validation and validation failed all the fields get their submitted values.
This is OK for some fields but not for others.
How can I leave some fields blank after an unsuccessful validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can set it manually like this 
in side the form use

```
$password->setValue("");
```

outside the form use

```
$form->getElement('password')->setValue("");
```

Comment: I have tried setValue when creating the element but that didn't work. I have now tried to set the value after the validation and that does work now. It seems that the isValid function set's the values of the elements.